# Stop increase width after a perticular width in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chat

I am creating a website which have chat support. I want to make its look exactly same as gmail chat means user can resize chat field.

I have made it almost like that but one problem is there: When I resize any field and if size reaches at 1100px then it should stop increase further but it doesn't stops. I made code for it but it has some problem. My code is as below:

Html code is:

```
<div class="chat">

<div class="chatt-demo" id="resizeDiv" style="border: 1px solid #000;width:100px;height:100px;margin left: 10px;">First
</div>
    <div class="chatt-demo" id="resizeDiv" style="border: 1px solid #000;width:100px;height:100px;margin left: 10px;">First
</div>
    <div class="chatt-demo" id="resizeDiv" style="border: 1px solid #000;width:100px;height:100px;margin left: 10px;">First
</div>
    <div class="chatt-demo" id="resizeDiv" style="border: 1px solid #000;width:100px;height:100px;margin left: 10px;">First
</div>
</div>
```

and jQuery code is:

```
$('.chatt-demo').resizable({
                    //containment: ".chart-area",
                    maxHeight: 580, 
                    //maxWidth: 300, 
                    minHeight: 330,
                    minWidth: 200,
                    handles: "n, nw, w, sw",
                    resize: function(event, ui) {
                            // return value from another function
                            restrictSize(ui);
                    }

        });

function restrictSize(ui) {
        var w = GetWidths('.chatt-demo');

        function GetWidths(id) {
            var i = 0;
            maxwidth = 250; 

            $(id).not('.hide-show-chatted').each(function (index) {
                i += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
            });


            if(i > 1100){ 
             //if(maxwidth <= 0){ maxwidth = 250; }
             //maxheight = 250; ui.size.height = ui.size.height > maxheight ?              maxheight : ui.size.height; 
             //ui.size.width = ui.size.width > maxwidth ? maxwidth : ui.size.width;
             // ui.size.width = 500;

              ui.size.width = maxWidth;
              // here I have tried many solutions like fixed width and all but no succeess.
            }
        }
    }
```

In above code when size reaches 1100 then div automatically resize to around 250. but I want that It should not decrease but stop there, and user can't increase size further.

Pleaswe anyone help.

Comment: Because you are assigning `ui.size.width = maxWidth;` and `maxwidth = 250`. Change it.

Comment: And why not using `maxWidth: 1100` ???

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: @Wolff you can refer gmail chat system

Comment: I just want to stop resizing after 1100px width.

Comment: @Dharmeshpatel you can you tried this after apply **text-warping** on that div.

Comment: @Avishek can you please give example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it myself. Just change condition like below:

```
if(i > 1100){ 
    var mywdth = $('.chatt-demo').width();
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $('.chatt-demo').not('.ui-resizable-resizing , .hide-show-chatted').each(function(index) {
    totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
    });
    var myMaxWidth = parseInt(1100-totalWidth, 10);
    ui.size.width = myMaxWidth;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
ui.size.width = maxWidth;
```

with this:

```
return;
```

Comment: I have tried this but now that div goes upper line and is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

```
ui.size.width = maxWidth;
```

You have define the maxWidth= 250; so it get resize to 250.
You can try by setting it to 1100;

```
 ui.size.width = 1100;
```

Refer this

http://jsfiddle.net/Anuja_oab/ukXap/142/

Comment: Can you try to remove the resize function call and just set maxWidth:1100,

Comment: No but I want to give this facility.

Comment: Means remove the call   restrictSize(ui); from your resize options. maxWidth: 1100,.   it should work

Comment: mIn jsfiddle it is working fine. can you check firebug you might getting any error

Comment: I have tried it. but, Size can be increasable tii 1100px. so this solution is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want a user to be able to increase the size of your "chatt-demo" class to 1100px and, if it gets larger than that, it simply won't increase in width.

A simple CSS solution to this would be to add this to your CSS/styling:

```
.chatt-demo {
  max-width: 1100px;
  // alternatively max-width: 1100px !important; if the above doesn't do anything
}
```

Comment: chatt-demo is a div which is more than once(in parallel) . so other div alignment goes disturb :(

Comment: @Dharmeshpatel Then you need to change div classes, make a ".chatt-demo-limited" or something and add that tot he specific one you want limited.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap text on that div..

```
<div class="chatt-demo" id="resizeDiv" style="border: 1px solid #000;width:200px; max-width:1100px; word-wrap:break-word;height:100px;margin left: 10px;">your text here..
```

Comment: cant set max-width because there are more than 1 div with this class name.

Comment: Ok, then try this one without the `max-width`, but you have to use text-wrap here anyhow..